# How to reload libgdx unmanaged Texture after OpenGL context loss

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm downloading images over the network and add them to my libgdx UI as Image actors using this:

```
Pixmap pm = new Pixmap(data, 0, data.length);
Texture t = new Texture(pm);
TextureRegion tr = new TextureRegion(t,200,300);
TextureRegionDrawable trd = new TextureRegionDrawable(tr);
Image icon = new Image();
icon.setDrawable(trd);
```

Given this I need some way of reloading the texture data since it is lost when the OpenGL context is lost (e.g. because the screen goes to sleep).

I've tried making my own manager class, adding

```
DynamicTextureManager.register(t, pm); // Register texture together with the source pixmap
```

to the above snippet, and in `resume()` I do:

```
DynamicTextureManager.reload();
```

The manager class:

```
public class DynamicTextureManager {
    private static LinkedHashMap<Texture, Pixmap> theMap = new
      LinkedHashMap<Texture,Pixmap>();
    public static void reload() {
        Set<Entry<Texture,Pixmap>> es = theMap.entrySet();
        for(Entry<Texture,Pixmap> e : es) {
            Texture t = e.getKey();
            Pixmap p = e.getValue();

            t.draw(p, 0, 0);
        }   
    }

    public static void register(Texture t, Pixmap p) {
        theMap.put(t, p);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't help - I still end up with the texture being unloaded and white areas instead of the image.

How should this be done? I haven't been able to find any code demonstrating this!

Comment: My guess is that a `Texture` does not _magically_ recreate the underlying texture handle. Try recreating the `Texture` itself, or switch to so-called _managed_ texture data (check the subclasses of `TextureData`; `PixmapTextureData` does not support this notion.

Comment: I have a task which is very similar to this. I have not done it yet, but if I get it working (which I think will involve rebuilding the Pixmap from the binary data) I will update this with an answer.

Comment: @Jyro117 I added my current solution as an answer, feel free to improve!

Comment: Ah excellent, thank you for adding your solution. I will be sure to look it over in more detail in the next couple days!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my solution as a reference. I now register the Image object and the Pixmap object with my manager, on reload() the Texture is re-created from the Pixmap and I set the new Texture for the old Image. Works for me, but more elegant solutions are welcome.

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
public class DynamicTextureManager {
    private static final class MapData {
        Pixmap pixmap;
        int width;
        int height;
    }

    private static WeakHashMap<Image, MapData> theMap = new WeakHashMap<Image, MapData>();

    public static void reload() {
        Set<Entry<Image, MapData>> es = theMap.entrySet();
        for (Entry<Image, MapData> e : es) {
            Image i = e.getKey();
            MapData d = e.getValue();

            Texture t = new Texture(d.pixmap);
            TextureRegion tr;
            if(d.width == -1 || d.height == -1) {
                tr = new TextureRegion(t);
            }
            else {
                tr = new TextureRegion(t,d.width, d.height);                
            }
            TextureRegionDrawable trd = new TextureRegionDrawable(tr);
            i.setDrawable(trd);
        }
    }

    public static void register(Image i, Pixmap p) {
        MapData d = new MapData();
        d.pixmap = p;
        d.width = -1;
        d.height = -1;
        theMap.put(i, d);
    }

    public static void register(Image i, Pixmap p, int width, int height) {
        MapData d = new MapData();
        d.pixmap = p;
        d.width = width;
        d.height = height;

        theMap.put(i, d);
    }

}
```