# Saving texture with Preferences

Tags: android, libgdx, android-preferences, object-object-mapping

So what Im trying to achive is: When the user purchases a new item (a texture) they can click a button to replace the old Item(texture) with the new one. 
What got in my mind first was Objectmaps. So I created this:

```
ObjectMap<Integer, Texture> screenMap = new ObjectMap<Integer, Texture>();
```

Im only using two items at the moment just to get a hang of it:

```
screenMap.put(prefs.getInteger("stoneOne", 0), sdStone);

screenMap.put(prefs.getInteger("stoneTwo", 1), stone_3);
```

Here´s the methods I use to change the texture:

```
public void setStone1() {
    stoneImage = new Image(screenMap.get(0));

}

public void setStone(int screenId) {
    stoneImage = new Image(screenMap.get(screenId));

  }
```

And now to the part I can figure out:

```
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("preferences");
                    prefs.putString("textField", textField.getText());
                    prefs.putString("textArea", textArea.getText());
                    prefs.getInteger("stone", );
                    prefs.putInteger("stone", );
                    prefs.flush();
```

I have no Idea what Integer to put in there as you can see I even left it out right now. I tried the screenId integer but it´s not reachable since it is in a void? P.S never mind the weird names I got for things. I took some code from an old project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to walk for another way.

1. [Save Texture to sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906559/libgdx-saving-textures-to-avoid-context-loss).
2. Save path to file into preferences.

---

```
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("preferences");
                        prefs.putString("texture_one_path", "/sdcard/tex1.jpeg");
                        prefs.putString("texture_two_path", "/sdcard/tex2.jpeg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sergey is right.  Textures are heavy and big, and you could potentially have tons of them.  That's meant for the SD card.

Preferences are lightweight, secure configuration files used on mobile devices. They're usually encrypted, too, so accessing them always has a cost. They're used usually for user settings, login information, etc.  The Android extrapolation of Preferences is called SharedPreferences.  Here's the doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

The iOS concept of "SharedPreferences" is called NSUserDefaults, and here's its page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html

Bottom line: you shouldn't be saving much information to the preferences.   Use it for strings, global values, user settings (volume level, user credentials, turn off gore, etc.)  For large string data, use raws.  For large media, use SD card.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Very informative. Thank you. 
If I understood you right, I should save the Textures to the SD card using Preferences? Like Sergey said. 
The thing is, I can´t see how the code Sergey posted will solve my issue. Yes the texture is being saved into the sdCard. But what should I write instead of "texture_one_path" for example? Just my textFields name? And how will this code ensure that when the user restarts the app, the right texture is being drawn?

Comment: Prefs take two arguments: key and value.  It's essentially a hash-map/dictionary.  You want to create a generic key for X texture, then save the generated local path that is specific to the device as the value.  Users may have variations of file paths, SD cards (multiple cards, even), etc., so having the distinct path is useful.

You should also maybe attempt to try-catch yourself that if the key-value pair doesn't exist, make them.  This is a safety scenario for a user who has changed/formatted their card or moved files from where you expected them to be.

Comment: Wow thanks, finally someone that´s pedagogical. So I store a key that works as a reference to X texture.  How I then use that key to ensure that the texture associated with that key is drawn Im not sure?  With try-catch? Do you maybe have an example on this? This is a new area for me.

Comment: Let's say you want the file path to a grass texture.  You go to your prefs and request the value for GRASS_TEXTURE_KEY.  If there's no value for that key, you need to make the texture.  Do all your work to figure out the SD card path, make your texture, save it to that path, and put the file path value into your prefs for the GRASS_TEXTURE_KEY. If the pref key exists, load the texture from the path (because it's already been made).  The try-catch is just to be safe that the texture truly does exist, hasn't been erased, the SD card hasn't been changed, etc.